# How to get formInputs in the commonEventObject from gmail add-on in python alternative runtime?

Tags: flask, google-workspace-add-ons

I am trying to develop a gmail add-on, and have successfully used my deployment resource to send requests to my http endpoint. When I click a button in my add-on, I log the contents of the request from my flask application to the google cloud console. In request.data, I am able to see a commonEventObject. It looks like this:

```
"commonEventObject": {"hostApp": "GMAIL", "platform": "WEB"}
```

However, what I am looking for in the commonEventObject is "formInputs", as described in the JSON schema: https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes#common-event

Here is what the JSON for my button which triggers the request looks like:

```
{
                    "buttonList": {
                        "buttons": [
                            {
                                "text": "Default text button",
                                "onClick": {
                                    "action": {
                                        "function": "https://myendpointaddress.run.app/click_action"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

The logs that I am viewing from google cloud originate from python like this:

```
@app.route('/click_action', methods=['POST'])
def click_action():
  print(request.data)
```

Here is my deployment resource:

```
{
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "My logging add on",
      "logoUrl": "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/googlematerialicons/markunread_mailbox/v6/black-24dp/1x/gm_markunread_mailbox_black_24dp.png",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "https://myendpointaddress.run.app/handle_post"
      }
    },
    "gmail": {
      "contextualTriggers": [{
        "unconditional": {
        },
        "onTriggerFunction": "https://myendpointaddress.run.app/handle_post"
      }]
    },
    "drive": {
    },
    "calendar": {
    }
  }
}
```

Any and all advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the description of formInput, found in the schema here https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes#common-event is very literal. It shows the *values* of the widgets in the card. If you don't set any "value" fields in your widgets, it has no data to send, and is seemingly omitted from the commonEventObject.